# TinyMCE: tinyMCE.init() on not yet appended <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-4

So, basically, I want to create a richtextbox even if there is no `<textarea>` yet. I want to append the richtextbox myself. Not by **tinyMCE**. The problem is I think that after appending this, I wont have any tinyMCE events.

What I have in mind is like...

`$("<textarea></textarea>").tinyMCE({options})` and this will return the html string of the richtextbox. That way, I can append the html string myself. Take note, it should work perfectly especially the events.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `<textarea>` through javascript and append it to the DOM just before you want to render the editor on screen. However you will need to use an `id` for the textarea.

```
//an editor id needs to be used in this method
var editorId = "#myId";
var options = {
    //options

}
//Creates an editor instance and adds it to the EditorManager collection.
tinyMCE.createEditor(editorId, options);

//get the editor instance by its id 
var editor = tinyMCE.get(editorId);

//get the root element you want insert the editor into. (E.g. body element)
var root = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

//create a textarea element
var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
//set its id
textarea.setAttribute("id", editorId);
//append it to the root element
root.appendChild(textarea);

//register your events
registerEvents(editor);

//display editor on screen
editor.render();
//set content of editor
editor.setContent("<h1>Hello World!</h1><p>Hello World!</p>");

//retrieve content from editor
var htmlContent = editor.getContent();

console.log(htmlContent);

function registerEvents(editor) {
  editor.on("init", function(e) {
    console.log("Init", e);
  });

  editor.on("focus", function(e){
    console.log("Focus", e);
  });

  editor.on("blur", function(e){
    console.log("Blur", e);
  });
}
```

Here is the example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/1swwprda/1/).